# After receiving the input in hexadecimal I would like to know how to output the SHA1 hash function

Tags: python, hash, hex

If 'a' is hashed,

```py
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.sha1(b'aa')
hex_Hash = hash.hexdigest()
print(hex_Hash)
```

I wrote the above code, but the desired result (38469e8ea8e72d0b889f1905195e2f4b79b5bb50) does not come out. How should I write the code?

Comment: How did you get your expected hash?

Comment: @C.Nivs I was wrong. I was trying to get the hash of the letter 'a', but I got the hash of the letter '\n'. The hash of a is only an example, and I am wondering how to output the value entered in hexadecimal as SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you got adc83b...fc from, but it is the sha-1 hash of the byte string containing a single newline: `b'\n'`.

```
>>> hashlib.sha1(b'\n').hexdigest()
'adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc'
```

========

Based on the comments below, it seems the original poster is actually asking about.  The hexdigest was just intended to be an example of the reverse of what they were looking for.  I think.

```
bytearray.fromhex('aa')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What I wanted was to take the hexadecimal value 'aa' as input and output it as a SHA1 hash.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with SHA-1?  You asking how to convert a string consisting of hexadecimal digits into a byte string?  See addendum to my code.

Comment: I want to write code a function like this page.(https://v2.cryptii.com/hexadecimal/sha1)